# how I can deactivate the writing of points after the user to seize a point

Tags: jquery, currency

I have one fields of amount, how I can deactivate the writing of points after the user to seize a point bu jquery function.
You should not seize more that a point.

```
$('#montant-total').change(function() { 
    $( 'tr:last' ).find("td:last").text(messages['montant incorrecte']).hide();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var patternMontant = /^\$?(([0-9]{0,10}))?\.[0-9]{2}$/;
    if(!patternMontant.test(inputVal)) {    
        $( 'tr:last' ).find("td:last").text(messages['montant incorrecte']).show().css("color","red");
        $(this).val('0.00');    
    }
});
$('#montant-total').keyup(function(e){
    var montantVal = $(this).val();
    point = true;
    if (montantVal.indexOf(".") >= 0){
        point = false;
    }
    if(montantVal.length == 10 && point  ){
        $(this).val(montantVal+'.');
    }   
});
```

the customer wants no plugin (maskMoney or autoNumeric) If there is a method to prevent the seizure of a point example: 156.36 instead of 1.56.56 After 10 input the system is going to seize the point automatically But before we can seize "."

Comment: You want to allow the user to be able to place only one dot (.)? E.g. to be able to write `100.25` but not `100.25.100`?

Comment: yes, Exactly The pattern # ### ### ###.##

Comment: "The customer wants no plugin" - is the customer your teacher? What customer would want to spend money having you solve a solved problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code wants to forbid the sizure of another dot(.) or (,), your fiels accepts only one dot(.) or (,)

$('#montant-total').keypress(function(event){

```
var montantVal = $(this).val();

 if (montantVal.indexOf(".") >= 0){

     var charCode = event.which;

     if (charCode == 44 || charCode == 46)  { return false;   }

     }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maskMoney plugin that will do the job for you. You can get it [**here**](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney).

Just download the plugin, include it in your page after jQuery and do

```
$('#montant-total').maskMoney();
```

You can also pass an options object to the function to format it according to your needs.E.g.

```
$("#name").maskMoney({

  prefix : '$'

});
```

Comment: Thank you,
 but the customer wants no plugin (maskMoney  or autoNumeric) 
If there is a method to prevent the seizure of a point
 example: 156.36 instead of 1.56.56
After 10 calculate(code) the system is going to seize the point automatically
But before we can seize import(matter) "."